# How do you display the Product version in WiX-made MSI file properties?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

How do I have the Product version displayed in the MSI file properties (as displayed by Windows Explorer)?

Our installer is created using WiX. All we see is the product GUID displayed as the Revision Number in the Details tab of the MSI file properties.

We'd like to have the product version (e.g.: `5.0.1.12345`) so that the support team (and customers) can easily check the version of a given file.

Answer (score 12):

Simply add the **Comments attribute** to the Package tag as below.

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Comments="Version: 5.0.1.12345" />
```

There is no version property to be set. So as an alternative we are adding it to the comments attribute. So it can be seen in the properties of the msi.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think that you can actually set a file version on MSI files in WIX. What we do is that we edit the description property of the Package.

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Description="Version: !(bind.FileVersion.filD6DA798364FCF1273EEE80AEF914C743)" InstallScope="perMachine" ...
```

And then we also make sure that the same version is used for the Product:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.FileVersion.filD6DA798364FCF1273EEE80AEF914C743)" ...
```

The description is visible in your MSI file properties and so the version will be visible in the description. I hope that is what you want!

Comment: By also putting it into the Name attribute of the Product node, you will see the version number also on the welcome page.

<Product Id="*" Name="Product Name !(bind.FileVersion.mainfile)" ...>

Answer (score 0):

(Just to elaborate on the other 2 answers by @LeoN and @westerstrom, I thought I'd show how those WiX attributes show in File Explorer)

### WiX 3

In WiX 3.x, we can we `<Product Name="" Version>`, and `<Package Description="" Comments="" />`:

```
<Wix>
    <Product
        Name="Product-Name !(bind.fileVersion.File_MyProgram_exe)"
        Version="$(var.VersionNumber)"
    >
        <Package
            Description="Product-Package-Description !(bind.FileVersion.File_MyProgram_exe)"
            Comments="Product-Package-Comments !(bind.FileVersion.File_MyProgram_exe)"
        />
```

...which appear like so:

| Wizard | File Details |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

| File Explorer Columns |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] |  |

- `<Product Name=""` corresponds to the text in the Wizard and the titlebar text, but not any `.msi` file properties nor File Explorer columns.
- `<Package Description=""` corresponds to **Description > Subject** and no columns.
- `<Package Comments=""` corresponds to **Description > Comments** and the *Comments* column in File Explorer.
- Only the `<Product Manufacturer=""` and `<Package Comments=""` appear in File Explorer columns, while all of the other File Explorer columns for Descriptions and Versions are all blank (surprisingly).

### WiX 4

In Wix 4 the `<Product>` and `<Package>` elements are combined but the end result is the same.