# How to add application version to the MSI file properties?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7

I have a application which is using `Wix` to create installer. Is there a way to add `version number` (build number) to the properties of `MSI` as shown below

Here google chrome installer added version in `comment` section.

[image]

Comment: BTW see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960642/how-do-you-display-the-product-version-in-wix-made-msi-file-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties in the details is known as the SummaryInformationStream and can be set via various attributes on the Package element.  In this case it's the Comments attribute.

Please note that this field is not the actual version of the MSI.  That will always be the ProductVersion property as set by the Product element's Version attribute.